# Proving $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=x^3$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

Can anyone verify the steps in my proof are correct?

Scratch work:
$|f(x)-f(y)| =|x^3-y^3|=|x-y||x^2+xy+y^2|$ (at this point note that we already know $|x-y|<\delta$ for some $\delta>0$)
$$|x-y||x^2+xy+y^2|<\delta|x^2+xy+y^2| $$
We now use the triangle inequality several times to find:
$$\delta|x^2+xy+y^2| \le \delta(|x^2| +|x||y|+|y^2|) $$
Looking at our domain, we know that at most $|x^2|=|x||y|=|y^2|=1$. So,
$$\delta(|x^2| +|x||y|+|y^2|) \le 3\delta $$

Proof:
We wish to prove that $\forall \varepsilon>0 \text{ }\exists \delta>0 \text{ } \forall x,y\in[-1,1],|x-y|<\delta:|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$

$\varepsilon >0$ is given, we choose $\delta = \varepsilon/3$ then $x,y$ satisfying $|x-y|<\delta=\varepsilon/3$ are given.

$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|x^3-y^3|=|(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)|=|x-y||x^2+xy+y^2|<\delta|x^2+xy+y^2| $$
By the triangle inequality
$$\delta|x^2+xy+y^2| \le \delta(|x^2|+|x||y|+|y^2|)\le3\delta \le3(\varepsilon/3)=\varepsilon $$

Hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on the domain $[-1,1]$

Comment: Seems ok to me.

Comment: Note: Max of $ |x^2+xy+y^2|=3$ on $[-1,1]$. Helps?

Comment: Note :  a very general result is the Heine–Cantor theorem, stating that every continuous function on a  bounded closed interval is uniformly continuous.

Comment: If you are particularly fond of inequalities then this is the way to go.  If not (like many of us) appeal to the mean-value theorem: *For $x,y\in [-1,1]$, we know that $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(\xi)||x-y|$ for some point $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$.  So if $M=\max_{t\in [-1,1]}|f'(t)|$ then  $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|$*.